# bash: trap an interrupt and "forward" it to background process

Tags: linux, bash, signals

I've got a bash script that runs another bash script in the background and then continues doing its own processing.  In the "outer" script (named scriptB.sh), I use `$!` to get the PID of the "inner" script (named scriptC.sh).  In both scripts I have a trap on the interrupt signal.

If I run the inner script standalone and press Ctrl-C during its execution, I see the interrupt signal get trapped and the script exits as requested in the trap.

If I run the outer script and press Ctrl-C, the outer script's trap sees the interrupt and attempts to issue a "kill" on the inner script's process ID using the interrupt signal, but the inner script's trap does not see it and the inner script continues processing normally.  I'm confident the PID is correct because if I switch the kill to a `kill -9` instead of a `kill -INT` or `kill -2` the inner script is immediately killed as expected.

So my question is: why does a `kill -INT` or `kill -2` not trigger the interrupt trap in my inner script?

### scriptB.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Run scriptC in the background and get its PID
./scriptC.sh &
pid_c=$!
echo "scriptC PID: $pid_c"

#This one will kill the inner script, but uses "-9" instead of "-INT" or "-2"
#trap '{ echo "requesting kill $pid_c" ; kill -9 $pid_c ; echo "requested kill $pid_c" ; }' INT

#This one does NOT trigger the interrupt trap in the inner script
trap '{ echo "requesting kill $pid_c" ; kill -2 $pid_c ; echo "requested kill $pid_c" ; }' INT

echo "Sleeping for 5"
sleep 5

echo "scriptB.sh has completed"
```

### scriptC.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap '{ echo "scriptC.sh received interrupt - exiting" ; exit 1; }' INT

for number in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    echo "scriptC: $number"
    sleep 1
done

echo "scriptC.sh has completed"
```

Comment: From the bash man page: `When job control is  not in  effect, asynchronous commands ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Can you tell when job control is not in effect? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: @x-yuri Generally, job control is in effect for interactive shells.  There are some subtleties and exceptions, but that's the easiest way to think about it.  In this case, the shell scripts are not being run interactively, job control is not in effect.  You can try enabling it with `set -m`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Indeed, sounds like a reasonable explanation, and I have [my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676835/setting-a-trap-for-int-doesnt-work-in-a-subshell) answered. But I've probably managed to run in one of those subtleties. Like `-m` is set, but job control is disabled: `(echo $-; sleep 1 & fg)`. And actually it's not exactly clear what they mean by job control. `kill` and `wait` are listed under the [job control builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html). Okay, when JC is disabled they probably don't take job specs.